# Помогите найти classpath

Tags: java, classpath

В документации на библиотеку сказано, что файл настроек должен лежать в classpath. Как найти где этот classpath в моем проекте?

Comment: classpath в вашем случаи это путь к .jar файла библиотеки. Так если бы вы хотели подключить библиотеку то в classpath указали бы именно путь к файлу .jar. Впрочем ищете .jar архив. (Все адэкватные библиотеки его содержат). Если же его нет то ищите папку bin с скомпилироваными .class файлами вашей скачаной библиотеки

Comment: а как вы программу запускаете?